# Click on button doesn't respond when clicked on text

Tags: jquery, button

I made a navigation bar with two click on buttons. One responds perfectly when you click on the text and or 5px around (padding is 5px) but the other only responds when you click within 5px around so not on the text. They have the same code but I'm new to JS so maybe I did something wrong (just copied the code and put a '2' behind the second one). Can anyone help me so that the click on happens on the text only and not around. Also, there is a blue border when you click on it. I set border to :none but doesn't seem to be it. Thanks!

```
    <div class="col-12 navbar-0">
<div class="col-10 col-container col-center-block navbar-1">

<div class="colom col-3 home"><strong><a href="index.php">HOME</a></strong></div>

<div class="colom col-3 dropdown aanbod">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><strong>ONS AANBOD</strong></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content col-12">
    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">WebDesign</a>
    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6">Retoucheren</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="colom col-3 dropdown2 portfolio">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2 col-12">
    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4">Websites</a>
    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7">Retoucheringen</a>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="colom col-3 contact"><strong><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8">CONTACT</a></strong></div>

  </div>
</div> 

<style>
/* Navigation */
.navbar-0 {
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-1 {
  text-align: center;
    color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 0px;
}

  .home, .contact {
    padding:5px;
  }

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color: white;
    color: #FB4D4D;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #FB4D4D;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block; border: none;}
/*2e drop*/
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color: white;
    color: #FB4D4D;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content2 a {
    color: #FB4D4D;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block; border: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Not fully clear about your question. Your first button is working as you expected right? Or you want click only for text not the padding?

Comment: .dropbtn2 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 0px;
        margin:0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

Comment: .dropdown2 {
        position: relative;margin: 5px;
    }

Comment: change your 2 classes like above classes then click will work only for text

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. The solution is similar to the one giving by Rakib underneath this ons but all it does is remove the padding and now I can't get the submenu to drop down as te button doesn't seem to affect the text. As you said: I only want to menu to drop down when clicked on the text. For the first dropdown it works perfectly though. The second one is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example. This will also remove the blue border when you will click on the button. `button:focus {outline:0;}` it will remove the blue border. Now this will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen backgrounds with centered content">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-12 navbar-0">
        <div class="col-10 col-container col-center-block navbar-1">
            <div class="colom col-3 home"><strong><a href="index.php">HOME</a></strong></div>
            <div class="colom col-3 dropdown aanbod">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">ONS AANBOD</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content col-12">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">WebDesign</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6">Retoucheren</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colom col-3 dropdown2 portfolio">
                <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">PORTFOLIO</button>
                <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2 col-12">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4">Websites</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7">Retoucheringen</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colom col-3 contact"><strong><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8">CONTACT</a></strong></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
    /* Navigation */

    .navbar-0 {
        height: auto;
    }

    .navbar-1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .home,
    .contact {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Button */

    .dropbtn {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

    .show {
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }
    /*2e drop*/
    /* Dropdown Button */

    .dropbtn2 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .dropdown2 {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content2 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content2 a {
        color: #FB4D4D;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

    .dropdown-content2 a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

    .show {
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }

    button:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    /*If you bind 2 onclick then only last one will fire*/

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            removeShow("dropdown-content");
        }

        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
            removeShow("dropdown-content2");
        }
    }

    function removeShow(className) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: For accessibility reasons you should not do just `button:focus {outline:0;}`

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it still doesn't work. The blue border is gone after you click it but the second clickdown doesn't work at all now. Correct me if I'm wrong but didn't you just adjust the padding and margin? I want to submenu to drop down as soon as you click the text, not the padding... Copied the whole code and it didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Can you provide me full source code to see the problem? Can't understand your requirement fully. I didn't add to open dropdown functionality i just solved click to text problem(you will have to update the those 2 functions with your own code). Please update your question with full source code. I need to see your JS code.

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      } } }}
</script>

Comment: <script>
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code. Now it will work. You were binding 2 onclick events but actually clicking will fire only last one. So your first event was not triggering that's the reason dropdown1 was working. Please don't forget to approve it as correct answer :).

Comment: Here is the fiddle in case if you need: https://jsfiddle.net/6azmod5m/2/ . You can also use full code in my answer as well.

Comment: Rakib, thank you, this code works perfectly :) I had no time yesterday so I'll study the code today to better understand JS. I'm relatively new to building websites (doing it as a hobby) so any help is more than welcome ;)

Comment: @Rakib If I want to add a third clickdown button, how does it work? I analysed the code and came to the conclusion that in terms of CSS it's just copy paste. So I tried to just copy the second button and add '3' instead of '2' but that doesn't work. I think it's the JavaScript. I tried to copy paste that as well (only the '2') but no luck... Can you please help me understand this? Greatly appreciated!